# Audit for EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, audit

I would like to implement audit functionality using EF Core.

I mean would like to log every transaction/action such as Create, update and delete in DB table.

I have searched on google and found some library and solution.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.EntityFramework.Core/

https://beeming.net/data/2017/1/easily-adding-auditing-to-a-entity-framework-code-first-project

Can some one suggest me best practices for auditing for EF Core 
Note: I am using EF Core 2.X

Comment: With the first library you mentioned [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) you can configure the output to save the audits to another EF context, to the file system and much more. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#storage-providers).

Comment: Another library that allow auditing is EF Plus: https://entityframework-plus.net/audit

Answer (score 2):

The basic process for auditing is to override the SaveChanges() method on the DbContext and plug in some logic. The DbContext has a ChangeTracker property that makes it super easy to access the before and after values